# Переслать файл по http не считывая его целиком в оперативную память? (HttpClient)

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, httpclient

**Задача:**

Есть большой файл на диске который мы хотим отправить на сервер по http используя наше приложение написанное на dotnet core.

**Вопрос:**

Подскажите как переслать файл с клиента на сервер не считывая его целиком в оперативную память?

Comment: Так там же должно быть все просто, открываете Stream нужного файла, дальше отправляете, например так: `await httpClient.PostAsync("Адрес", new StreamContent(fileStream));` (очень упрощенный пример, но суть думаю ясна).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А зачем вы засовываете файл в память, ведь есть же такая вещь, как Stream.

Самый простой пример использования будет таким:

1. Открываем `stream` указанного файла, для файлов это `FileStream`. Нам нужно только чтение:

   ```
   using var fileSteam = File.Open("SomeFile", FileMode.Open);
   ```
2. Далее для отправки нам нужно другой `stream`, который предназначен для отправки данных на сервер, зовется он `StreamContent` и принимает любой другой `stream` (будь то память, файл или что либо еще):

   ```
   using var content = new StreamContent(fileSteam);
   ```
3. Отправляем данные на сервер. `HttpClient` имеет все необходимые методы отправки, выбирайте нужный. Я например буду отправлять на сервер `transfer.sh`, который принимает `PUT` запросы:

   ```
   var resp = await client.PutAsync("https://transfer.sh/myFile.exe", content);
   ```
4. Ну остается нам прочитать ответ от сервера:

   ```
   var respContent = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   ```

Для теста я отправлю то, что было под рукой (драйвер для видеокарты), вес его ~500мб

[image: Test]

Как видите, потребление памяти у меня в районе 75мб, файл отправляется напрямую с диска. Если чуть подождать, то сервер отдает статус 200 (OK) и в ответ ссылку на файл, что показывает успешную загрузку файла на сервер.

[image: Result]

---

Если нам надо отправлять сразу несколько файлов, то для этого существует `MultipartFormDataContent`, который позволяет добавить в себя несколько данных для отправки, будет выглядеть все примерно так:

```
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    streamContent1,
    streamContent2
};

content.Add(streamContent3);

var resp = await client.PostAsync("Адрес", content);
```

Я очень многое тут опустил, но думаю основная суть будет понятна.

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ, в дополнение к моему вопросу, как думаете как можно отправить несколько файлов как один(файлы являются частями целого), конечно можно их объеденить в один и воспользоватся вашим методом, но есть ли способ не объеденять их в один?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Это лучше вам задать отдельным вопросом, может кто поможет. В теории можно это все объединять в `Stream`. Я например нашел [такой](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26609207/) код, где делается свой `Stream`, который на вход принимает  коллекцию других потоков, попробуйте, может это то, что вам нужно.